# SQL query with too many loops

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have a function that takes the name of a category and return all the filters groups associated with that category, as well as the filters associated to each group. 
But there are too many loops and query going on, is there a way to improve the code below ??

```
 public function getCategoryFilters($category_id) {

    // get category filter groups
    $query = $this->app['db']->query("SELECT filter_group_id
    FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "category_filter
    WHERE category_id = '" . (int)$category_id . "'
    ");

    if($query->rows) :
        foreach ($query->rows as $group) :

            $filter_group_query = $this->app['db']->query("
            SELECT DISTINCT fg.filter_group_id, fgd.name, fg.sort_order
            FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "filter_group fg
            LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "filter_group_description fgd ON (fg.filter_group_id = fgd.filter_group_id)
            WHERE fg.filter_group_id = '" . $group['filter_group_id'] . "'
            AND fgd.language_id = '1'
            GROUP BY fg.filter_group_id
            ORDER BY fg.sort_order, LCASE(fgd.name)");

            foreach ($filter_group_query->rows as $filter_group) :
                $filter_data = array();

                $filter_query = $this->app['db']->query("
                    SELECT DISTINCT f.filter_id, fd.name FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "filter f
                    LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "filter_description fd ON (f.filter_id = fd.filter_id)
                    WHERE f.filter_group_id = '" . (int)$filter_group['filter_group_id'] . "'
                    AND fd.language_id = '1'
                    ORDER BY f.sort_order, LCASE(fd.name)");

                foreach ($filter_query->rows as $filter) :
                    $filter_data[] = array(
                            'filter_id' => $filter['filter_id'],
                            'name'      => $filter['name']
                    );
                endforeach;

                if ($filter_data) :
                    $filter_group_data[] = array(
                            'filter_group_id' => $filter_group['filter_group_id'],
                            'name'            => $filter_group['name'],
                            'filter'          => $filter_data
                    );
                endif;

            endforeach;

        endforeach;

        return $filter_group_data;

    endif;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on what you mean by 'improve'. If you want to improve code readability and make sure that someone can make sense of it later on, then you should create subfunctions, like Matei Mihai suggested in his answer.

I would do it like this (pseudocode):

```
public function getCategoryFilters($category_id) {
    //Declare subfunctions
    //Get the data concerning group filters
    private function getFilterGroupData($category_id) {
        ...
        mysqli query here
        ...
        $result = array();
        insert query results into $result using a loop
        return $result;
    }

    //Get specific filter data
    private function getFilterData($filter_group_id) {
        ...
        mysqli query here
        ...
        $result = array();
        insert query results into $result using a loop:
        for ($i = 0, $i < $mysqli_query->num_rows; $i += 1) {
            ...
        //Add $filter_group_id right here as you seem to need it in the results:
            $result[$i]['filter_group_id'] = $filter_group_id;
        }
        return $result;
    }

    //Get the data you need, populate an array with all the results
    $filter_groups_data = getFilterGroupData($category_id);
    $count = count($filter_groups_data);
    $all_filters_data = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i += 1) {
        $filter_data = getFilterData($filter_groups_data[$i];
        //Insert into final results
        array_push($all_filters_data, $filter_data);
    }   
    return $all_filters_data;
}
```

However, if you want to lessen the number of queries instead, you can write a more complicated query, doing a join of filter_group, filter_group_description, filter and filter_description tables right off the bat and then looping through the results only once.

You should consider this only if you are having troubles with script execution speed, as the query will be a lot less readable. Basically, just go:

```
SELECT ... FROM
filter_group 
INNER JOIN filter_group_description ON filter_group_id
INNER JOIN filter ON filter_group_id
INNER JOIN filter_description ON filter_id
WHERE ...
ORDER BY ...;
```

If you go this route, though, be sure to leave a comment describing just how the query works as SQL inside a PHP script with several JOINs is notoriously hard to debug and change.

Comment: I will implement both methods and see the difference between the two in terms of execution time. in case the second suggestion runs faster I will comment the functions solutions and keep it as reference of what's really going on. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

you could use the `in` clause to reduce the query-time;
like this:

```
foreach ($query->rows as $group) :
     $filter_group_ids[] = $group['filter_group_id'];
endforeach;

        $filter_group_query = $this->app['db']->query("
        SELECT DISTINCT fg.filter_group_id, fgd.name, fg.sort_order
        FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "filter_group fg
        LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "filter_group_description fgd ON (fg.filter_group_id = fgd.filter_group_id)
        WHERE fg.filter_group_id IN ('" . implode("','",$filter_group_ids) . "')
        AND fgd.language_id = '1'
        GROUP BY fg.filter_group_id
        ORDER BY fg.sort_order, LCASE(fgd.name)");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a method for each loop. By doing like this you will increase the readability and will simplify the code:

```
public function getCategoryFilters($category_id) {}

public function getFilterData($filterGroupIds) {}

// .....
```

Comment: True. But I am looking for something to improve the performance of this query